# Shell Script to fetch iostat details

Tags: linux, shell

Need to fetch iostat details and calculate the avg of  "%user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle"

I am using awk to achieve the same.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Is there any issue with what you're doing OR you're just looking for alternatives or a better approach?

Comment: why you need average , is that a valid measure?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `vmstat -s` of `sysstat`. Take a look : [Statistics of Various Counter](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-performance-monitoring-with-vmstat-and-iostat-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution for: [Assessing disk performance with the iostat command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/assess_disk_perf_iostat.htm)